# How might you determine how well distributed a set of data is?

Tags: r, plot, distribution

I have two datasets which contains a distrbution of 90 data points into 2 and 4 groups/rows and I would like to determine which one out of the two has better distributed the data and plot the result to visually see which one has done this. Better distribution means which one has made it so each group has a similar/same number of data. For example, we can see that the result of `Grouped 2` the second group contains larger values for each column compared to the first column so 1 of the 2 groups contains larger values which means its not well distributed among the 2 groups.

I quite new to R so I am unsure how I could go about doing this. Would appreciate any insight into what approach could be used.

R

Grouped into 4

```
Values <- matrix(c(1,   6,  3,  6,  6,  8,
                   3,   3,  5,  3,  3,  3,
                   6,   7,  6,  7,  5,  4,
                   9,   4,  4,  5,  5,  3), nrow = 4, ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE)
```

Grouped into 2

```
Values <- matrix(c(3,   6,  4,  3,  4,  6,
                   12,  9,  12, 12, 11, 9), nrow = 2, ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE)
```

Comment: You will need to define "better" before we can answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with some basic statistics, using hypothesis testing i.e. testing whether the two groups are statistically different or not. The `stats` package in R has a lot of tests that you can try and use, each with its own assumptions. Here is one:

Making the matrix

```
values <- matrix(c(3,   6,  4,  3,  4,  6,
                   12,  9,  12, 12, 11, 9), nrow = 2, ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE)
```

Conducting t-test

```
t.test(values[1, ], values[2, ], paired = FALSE)
```

Will give you this:

```
    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  values[1, ] and values[2, ]
t = -7.9279, df = 9.945, p-value = 1.318e-05
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -8.328203 -4.671797
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 4.333333 10.833333
```

The means of `values[1, ]` is smaller than `values[2, ]`, with a p-value of 1.3e-05.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I do not know much statistics so I am curious if a smaller p value means there is a larger difference and a larger one means there is little difference?

Comment: This can only be used with 2 rows?